# Merging Nested Objects with same key into single Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my Array in JavaScript, I want to merge teacher object below into combine single object to perform operations further.

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "ab",
    class: 1,
    grade: "A",
    teacher: {
      teacherName: "tab",
      age: 34,
      school: "ab pblc scl"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "cd",
    class: 2,
    grade: "B",
    teacher: {
      teacherName: "efg",
      age: 35,
      school: "cd pblc scl"
    }
  }
];
```

This is my Expected output. Here teacher object is combine with other single objects. Any idea how can I do this ?

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "ab",
    class: 3,
    grade: "B",
    teacherName: "kio",
    age: 38,
    school: "ab pblc scl"

  },
  {
    name: "de",
    class: 2,
    grade: "B",
    teacherName: "tde",
    age: 36,
    school: "de pblc scl"
   }

 }
];
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could destructure `teacher` and spread the rest of the array with `teacher` to a new object.

Methods:

- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to `teacher`,

  ```
  result = data.map(({ teacher, ...object }) => ({ ...object, ...teacher }));
                     ^ ^^^^^^^            ^
  ```
- [rest in object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) for getting all other properties,

  ```
  result = data.map(({ teacher, ...object }) => ({ ...object, ...teacher }));
                     ^          ^^^^^^^^^ ^
  ```
- [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for getting copies of own enumerable properties of the object

  ```
  result = data.map(({ teacher, ...object }) => ({ ...object, ...teacher }));
                                                 ^ ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^ ^
  ```

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "ab", class: 1, grade: "A", teacher: { teacherName: "tab", age: 34, school: "ab pblc scl" } }, { name: "cd", class: 2, grade: "B", teacher: { teacherName: "efg", age: 35, school: "cd pblc scl" } }],
    result = data.map(({ teacher, ...object }) => ({ ...object, ...teacher }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use spread operator to do it.

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "ab",
    class: 1,
    grade: "A",
    teacher: {
      teacherName: "tab",
      age: 34,
      school: "ab pblc scl"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "cd",
    class: 2,
    grade: "B",
    teacher: {
      teacherName: "efg",
      age: 35,
      school: "cd pblc scl"
    }
  }
];

const newData = data.map(d => {
  const dClone = Object.assign({},d);
  delete dClone.teacher;
  return {
    ...dClone,
    ...d.teacher
  }
})

console.log(newData);
```